# M2 - How to include custom theme directory less file path into my CMS block?

Tags: magento2.3.4, cms-block, less, custom-theme

I have created custom theme which is inherit from blank theme,

I have created more than one CMS block and include into CMS page for home page design.

One of my CMS block named **service banner**

In the CMS block i have created some design:

```
<div class=" container service-banner">

<div class="row">
<div> </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div> </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I have created **_cms_block.less** file under

**app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\ _cms_block.less**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container service-banner{
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    }
}
```

and imported into **_extend.less file**

```
@@import "_cms_block.less";
```

How to include custom theme directory CSS file into my CMS block?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder named Magento_Theme and place the CSS styles (in less format obviously) in the `_extend.less`(web/css/source) file.
2. This CSS will be applied to all the places the block is called.

You can place the CSS style in any of the _extend.less files in the theme. But it is good practice to place it under Magento_Theme folder.

If you want the CSS to be applied to a set of specific pages out of all the pages the block is being rendered, then differentiate the CSS codes using the class name of the body.

Example, product listing page contains the body class of `catalog-category-view` and product view page has the body class of `catalog-product-view`.

Comment: Yes, here i have created  _cms_block.less  under app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\_cms_block.less then import  _cms_block.less into _extend.less, My question how to add this path into my CMS Block(Not CMS Page)

Comment: My class name : class="container service-banner"   In my less file using @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container service-banner{
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    }
}

Comment: If you have created _cms_block.less under we/css/source of the theme itself, then import the file in _theme.less(web/css/source). Magento will load the CSS along with the other CSS codes.

Comment: What is the best practice, i want to add css to my cms block (not cms page)that's it.

Comment: If you want the CSS along with the block, then provide the CSS directly in the block itself. It is not possible to call .less files in the blocks created in the admin panel

Comment: Its not good practice right (for development i did like this) and also page load time increase. May i know how to achieve my task?

Comment: Finally done. add css inside _theme.less under app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\ _theme.less the css style will apply on CMS Block.

Comment: Same where i can add my js?

Comment: All the CMS (Block or Page) related styles can be kept under Magento_Cms/web/css/source/_extend.less file under theme. It is the best practice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117551/discussion-between-mathanagopal-s-and-zus).